# Testflight not installing completely

Tags: objective-c, ios8, testflight, beta-testing

I'm currently beta testing one of my apps via testflight but im having problems with the installation process.

Everything works fine up to the point, when one of my testers tries to install the app. After you tap install the downloading process stops at about 80%. 
If you minimize Testflight the app appears to be installed and can be used but the UX is poor.

In Testflight the app remains in the 80% install state:
[image: failed install]

If i install my app via xcode everything runs fine under iOS8.

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to me, any luck?

Comment: Hey man, I think i found the problem.. for me atleast, create a new build number and in Build Settings turn both of the 'Build Active Architecture Only' to No and it works for some reason

Comment: I was running with the default settings: Debug true, Release false which should result in a "fat" binary. 
Was your setting the same as mine while it was failing and setting the flag for Debug to fales solved it? (which would surprise me, as testflight should only get the release build)

Comment: Yes, mine was the same setup. It surprised me too. I thought the same. I don't get why it would affect it either as I agree, it should just be the release version being used. Perhaps it isn't it, this is my first release app so i've not really been this far. Let me know if it solves it.

Comment: Doesn't help for me unfortunately :/ still stuck at 80% install and app not working properly

Comment: Strange, you could try e-mail the testflight people, they replied pretty fast to me (within a day). I'm sure they'd be interested to hear about a case where it hangs at 80% without an error.

Comment: We are seeing the exact same thing, but our app works fine once the progress bar stalls at this 80% mark. It means our beta testers can use the app, it's just a very poor user experience as they don't realize it's usable with this stuck progress bar :-( I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening unfortunately

Comment: I fiigured out some of the issues with the microphone was my fault but nevertheless the 80% bug remains

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I discovered on a hunch that the CFBundleVersion should not contain leading zeros after a period.

`15.06011812 should be 15.6011812`

Once we fixed that, the installs completed in the UI of TestFlight (then the switch for the watch app showed up and worked).

Afterward, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30338463/2615958) searching for 'testflight progress'.

TestFlight thinks that it never finished installing because the CFBundleVersion in the installed app's Info.plist contains the leading zero which makes it an older version of the app. When I quit TestFlight and relaunched, it thought that there was an update available.

Until I tried installing the Watch App this was just an annoyance in the UI, but then it was preventing me from seeing the switch to install the Watch App.