# TestFlight is unable to complete testee app upgrades

Tags: ios, testflight

Recently, we found our internal testers and external testers can't update our new prerelease app.

We are using developer provisioning file to sign binary code. The prerelease app can be verified by itunesconnect.  It can be submitted to app store successfully.  Than our testers tried to use TestFlight to update the app. They pressed Update button beside the app icon in the TestFlight. The TestFlight never finish its job. The progress circle wouldn't complete.

Version:
TestFlight Version: 1.0.2(55),
XCode Version: 6.3 (6D570),
iOS Version: 8.1(12B411)  &  8.2(12D508)  &  8.3(12F70)

We have tried 3G network and WiFi network. We have tried all different Apple ID in TestFlight.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say this solution will suit for all other same scenarios, but for my case I got answer from Apple Bug Reporter's engineer.

> **Apple Developer Relations20-May-2015 05:08 AM**
>
> Engineering has provided the following feedback regarding this issue:
>
> We have figured out the issue. The TestFlight app doesn’t correctly
>   handle apps that include leading 0s in their versions strings.
>   Versions like 1.6.02 or 3.5.04 will fail to complete the install.
>
> Until this is fixed, please workaround it by using version numbers
>   without leading zeros (1.6.02 -> 1.6.2 or 3.5.04 -> 3.5.4).
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for spending so much time
>   gathering information on this issue, it really helped!
>
> Please provide your response or results by updating your bug report.

Comment: I just discovered this on a hunch while trying to figure out how to install a Watch App from TestFlight (The switch wouldn't show up because TestFlight always thought there was an update available). I wish this answer was more accessible.

Comment: I believe this is also the case for versions like `0.9xx`?

Comment: @tipycalFlow I haven't try it. Maybe!

Answer (score 2):

For beta release, you have to use same distribution profile which is used to publish.

Comment: You are right! It works. But, before we release first distribution app in AppStore, the development profile is fine, and no such problem.

Comment: The problem is back. I am using same distribution profile after second publish. But the TestFlight doesn't let upgrade circle complete. The app in the phone is new beta version actually. Is this an Apple bug?

Comment: Sorry, we believe there must be a bug in the TestFlight. After second  publish, we met the problem again. We start a Apple Bug Report now.